# FB.UI big thumbnail for link

Tags: facebook

How to I share a link with big thumbnail as picture. using java SDK FB.UI feed method?

No matter how big the picture i put as my thumbnail, Facebook in feeds does not appear as big thumbnail.

```
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'name',
                link: link,
                picture: picUrl,
                caption: 'caption',
                display: 'popup',
            }, function(response){console.log(response);});
```

Comment: **picture**:
The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on maximizing distribution for media content for more information on sizes."
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

Use 2X1 ratio pic

Like 800pix by 400pix image on ur wall it ll be crop to square but on news feed it will be a big central image with URL underneath. Don't forget to set meta tags of url page

Comment: It does not work, i have been using very big picture, it only show as old facebook link share with small thumbnail.

Comment: and the link will access to a dynamic page where the picture might not be there anymore. Maybe i need to create a static page for that. I just cant get the big central image on feed.

Comment: Use 1000px by 500px post it and check news feed not wall I m sure it works

Comment: tested, it is not comming, still old style small pic.

Comment: @m-farhan, the API doesn't support big thumbnails yet, maybe in the next version :)